# Pandas Resample Strange Zero Tolerance Behavior

Tags: pandas, time-series

I'm attempting to resample a time series in Pandas and I am getting some odd behavior:

```
print samples[196].base_df.to_string()
            Units    Sales
2008-07-03      3   820.00
2008-07-04      3   470.00
...
2010-06-22      1   335.00
2010-06-24      2   180.00
2010-06-30     -1 -2502.00


print samples[196].base_df.resample('15d', how='sum')
            Units          Sales
2008-07-03     17   3.149130e+03
2008-07-18     29   6.305210e+03
...
2010-06-08     18   5.204000e+03
2010-06-23      1  -2.322000e+03
2010-07-08      0  6.521324e-312
```

I would have expected the last value in the resampled series to be either zero or omitted. Is this expected behavior for the resample function? If helpful I can post the full time series, but it is a bit long...

Comment: Look at the keyword arguments ``closed`` and ``label``. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html